# LaTeX on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, latex

What's the best way to incorporate LaTeX into a WordPress blog?

It should render in every major browser (IE, FF, Safari, and Chrome).

Comment: This question is not a good fit for [se]. Some related questions might be on topic in [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few available plugins of varying quality. One problem most of the plugins have is the vertical alignment of the LaTeX-generated characters. Equations sit too high on the line most of the time. The only plugin I've found to get around this problem is [WP-QuickLaTeX](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/?page_id=1422) which works seamlessly. However, it doesn't handle displayed equations, only inline equations.
I don't know of a plug-in that gets vertical alignment correct and handles displayed equations. (And I've tried them all as far as I know.)

Comment: There's a load more information about solutions at http://sixthform.info/steve/wordpress/

Answer (score 3):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-latex/ is *the* answer ;-)

Developed by Automattic's Michael Adams and [live on WordPress.com](http://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/), it is well supported and maintained.

Answer (score 1):

It's not WordPress specific, but [jsLatex](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jsLaTeX) has been an option I've seen people use to get LaTeX into browsers.